# Bootstrap and Z-Index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with z-index attribute that I have included within a div that has a Pinterest Widget.

In a previous application that wasn't Bootstrap, I was able to simply set z-index: 2 which would help hide part of this Widget behind the Headline.

Here I have set the headline div and the parent column div to z-index:1
The Widget div and it's parent div to z:index:2

```
<div class="col-md-4 md-margin-bottom-20 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="z-index:1">
   <div class="">
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; z-index:1;">
           <div class="headline" style="z-index:1;">
               <h2>Recent Job Pictures</h2>
           </div>
           <div class="" style="z-index:2;">
               <div style="margin-top:-46px; z-index:2;">
                   <a data-pin-do="embedUser" href="http://www.pinterest.com/davincispainter/" data-pin-scale-width="65"  data-pin-scale-height="162" data-pin-board-width="360"></a>
               </div>
               <!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
               <script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried placing overflow:hidden within the widget div, but I can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

[My Test Site](http://petcenters.com/painters)

Any suggestion regarding this z-index would be appreciated.

Comment: Your pinterest widget has `margin-top:-46px`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @AnthonyValera Yes I want to hide the header part of the widget.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even though you have a `z-index` style applied to `.headline`, be sure to also include an appropriate `position` rule. `z-index` will only apply to elements with a `position` rule other than the default

[source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Since your element is rendered as transparent, if you wish to "hide" part of this widget, setting a `background-color` will satisfy this

```
.headline {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I added both styles all the way back to container content, although the widget is behind the title, you can still see it.  I will update the image.

Comment: @Paul this is because your element is rendered transparent. Adding `background-color: white` to `.headline` should "hide" your widget

Comment: Great! I have spend 2 hours and finally a merge between position:relative and z-index layers worked!!

Answer (score 5):

**1.)**

Assure your declaring a position with `z-index;` in your case, `position: relative;` is most optimal.

**2.)**

Make sure your declaring `z-index:` higher then that of which is pulled in by pintrest API / iframe.

**3.)**

Make sure you even need `z-index;` try just adding `position: relative;` to your element in Q.

```
.headline { 
    // your styles
    position: relative;
}
```

**4.)**

If nothing else works.. you can force it there with `position: absolute;` and `z-index;` *(though not recommended)*

Answer (score 2):

Z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than "static" (the default).

Answer (score 0):

**100% Working **Bootstrap 5 z-index classes:****

```
z-index-n2: This class represents z-index: -2. 
z-index-n1: This class represents z-index: -1. 
z-index-0: This class represents z-index: 0.
z-index-1: This class represents z-index: 1. 
z-index-2: This class represents z-index: 2. 
z-index-3: This class represents z-index: 3.
```

Comment: class="z-index-3" dont work

Comment: @Sebastian Here is my proof from browser console

.z-index-3 {
    z-index: 3 !important;
}

.position-absolute {
    position: absolute!important;
}

Comment: But there dont find the styling for z-index-3. i use Bootstrap 5.3

Answer (score -5):

In my particular case absolute positioning did the trick. Relative positioning was pushing down other bootstrap elements.

```
.headline { 
    z-index: 2147483647;
    position: absolute;    
}
```